# left div doesn't adjust to right divs height

Tags: html, css, media-queries

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEKZZ.png)

So I've have this irritating problem when smaller div doesn't follow the taller div. Is there a solution for this problem?

```
.right { float:right;}
.left { float: left; }

.row:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
<div class="row">   
        <div class=" col-3 col-m-12 right">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id facilisis augue, vel dictum velit. Nam rutrum, sem in finibus congue, neque sapien volutpat libero, ut pulvinar dui dolor non elit. Aliquam et rutrum orci, ut aliquet lorem. Maecenas eget nulla quam. Nullam sit amet ullamcorper augue.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id facilisis augue, vel dictum velit. Nam rutrum, sem in finibus congue, neque sapien volutpat libero, ut pulvinar dui dolor non elit. Aliquam et rutrum orci, ut aliquet lorem. Maecenas eget nulla quam. Nullam sit amet ullamcorper augue.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id facilisis augue, vel dictum velit. Nam rutrum, sem in finibus congue, neque sapien volutpat libero, ut pulvinar dui dolor non elit. Aliquam et rutrum orci, ut aliquet lorem. Maecenas eget nulla quam. Nullam sit amet ullamcorper augue.
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 col-m-12 left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id facilisis augue, vel dictum velit. Nam rutrum, sem in finibus congue, neque sapien volutpat libero, ut pulvinar dui dolor non elit. Aliquam et rutrum orci, ut aliquet lorem. Maecenas eget nulla quam. Nullam sit amet ullamcorper augue.
        </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "follow"? You want them to be the same height?  If so, your best bet is to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @cale_b Thats right I would like for the left div to be the same height as the right even if the left has no text and right does. I am not sure but this problem might also be because I am trying to make the design responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:table-cell` instead of float:

```css
.right, .left { display:table-cell; border:1px solid; }
```

```html
<div class="row">   
        <div class=" col-3 col-m-12 right">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id facilisis augue, vel dictum velit. Nam rutrum, sem in finibus congue, neque sapien volutpat libero, ut pulvinar dui dolor non elit. Aliquam et rutrum orci, ut aliquet lorem. Maecenas eget nulla quam. Nullam sit amet ullamcorper augue.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id facilisis augue, vel dictum velit. Nam rutrum, sem in finibus congue, neque sapien volutpat libero, ut pulvinar dui dolor non elit. Aliquam et rutrum orci, ut aliquet lorem. Maecenas eget nulla quam. Nullam sit amet ullamcorper augue.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id facilisis augue, vel dictum velit. Nam rutrum, sem in finibus congue, neque sapien volutpat libero, ut pulvinar dui dolor non elit. Aliquam et rutrum orci, ut aliquet lorem. Maecenas eget nulla quam. Nullam sit amet ullamcorper augue.
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 col-m-12 left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id facilisis augue, vel dictum velit. Nam rutrum, sem in finibus congue, neque sapien volutpat libero, ut pulvinar dui dolor non elit. Aliquam et rutrum orci, ut aliquet lorem. Maecenas eget nulla quam. Nullam sit amet ullamcorper augue.
        </div>
```

Comment: It works but when resizing the page the div doesn't position below when viewing on smaller screen it just keeps reduing the width but increases the height, what are my options in this situation?

Comment: never mind I fixed it I just added the line of code you gave me to the breakpoint of min-width: 1224px which is for dekstop - laptop view.